# Form is resetting page rather than displaying text

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, validation

Okay. So I am making a BMI calculator for both imperial and metric. The formula works and when it is not a form, the text displays, but i need to put it in a form to be validated - that's where my problem is. The submit buttons just seem to be refreshing the page rather than displaying the text. I'm not sure what I should be adding so it just displays the text rather than refreshing the whole page.

My JS -

```
$(function(calculateBMI) {

    // when the text field gets focus it gets ride of the default value
    //:text makes the browser check for ALL text fields
    $(':text').focus(function() {
        console.log('got focus');
        var field = $(this);
        //basically asks - is it blank? if not, put default value in
        if (field.val()==field.prop('defaultValue')) { 
            field.val(''); 
        } 
    }); 

    $(':text').blur(function() {
        console.log('lost focus');
        var field = $(this);

        //basically asks - is it blank? if not, put default value in
        if (field.val()=='') { 
            field.val(field.prop('defaultValue'));              
        } 

}); 


    $('#imperialunits').validate();
    $('#metricunits').validate();
 }); // end ready       


function bmiCalcI(){
    var iHeightFeet=Number(document.getElementById("iHeightFeet").value);
    var iHeightInch=Number(document.getElementById("iHeightInch").value);
    var iHeight=(iHeightFeet * 12)+iHeightInch;
    var iWeight=Number(document.getElementById("iWeight").value);

    var calcI_1=iWeight * 703;
    var calcI_2=iHeight * iHeight;
    var calcI_3=Math.round(calcI_1 / calcI_2);
    $("#outputI").text("Your BMI is: " + calcI_3);
}

function bmiCalcM(){
    var mHeight=Number(document.getElementById("mHeight").value);
    var mWeight=Number(document.getElementById("mWeight").value);

    var calcM_1=mHeight / 100
    var calcM_2=calcM_1 * calcM_1;
    var calcM_3=Math.round(mWeight / calcM_2);

    $("#outputM").text("Your BMI is: " + calcM_3);

}

</script>
```

And my HTML

```
<div class="results">
<div id="imperialunits tabs-1" class="calc">
    <h3>Imperial Units</h3>
    <p>Height:</p>
    <form id="imperial">
     <input type="text" id="iHeightFeet" value="ft" class="required digits">
     <input type="text" id="iHeightInch" value="in" class="required digits">
     <p>Weight:</p> 
     <input type="text" id="iWeight" value="lbs" class="required digits">
    <input type="submit" value="bmiCalcI" onclick="bmiCalcI();">
    <div id="outputI"></div>
    </form>
</div>

<div id="metricunits tabs-2" class="calc">
    <h3>Metric Units</h3>
    <form id="metric">
     <input type="text" id="mHeight" value="cm" class="required digits">
     <p>Weight:</p> 
     <input type="text" id="mWeight" value="kg" class="required digits">
    <input type="submit" value="bmiCalcM" onclick="bmiCalcM();">
    <div id="outputM"></div>
    </form>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

What's happening is you have defined your buttons as `type="submit"`, which means that when clicked they are going to submit the form. When a form has no action defined, it simply refreshes the page - and when that happens, the page reverts to its initial state.

You have a couple of options here.

The easiest option would be to change the buttons from an `input` to a `button` element

```
<button type="button" onclick="bmiCalcM();">Calculate</button>
```

You could also add on onsubmit to the `form` element to prevent refreshing

```
<form id="metric" onsubmit="return false;">
```

You could also use the `event.preventDefault()` function - a jQuery solution might look like

```
$('#metric').submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var mHeight=Number(document.getElementById("mHeight").value);
    var mWeight=Number(document.getElementById("mWeight").value);

    var calcM_1=mHeight / 100
    var calcM_2=calcM_1 * calcM_1;
    var calcM_3=Math.round(mWeight / calcM_2);

    $("#outputM").text("Your BMI is: " + calcM_3);

});
```

These would replace your calculation functions, so you would also need to remove the onclick in the submit buttons if you want to choose this solution.

Comment: The onsubmit="return false;" worked great! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

you should call "return false" in function if you don't need to refresh the page.
try this

```
<input type="submit" value="bmiCalcM" onclick="return bmiCalcM();">
```

And change your function bmiCalcM() as below:

```
function bmiCalcM(){
var mHeight=Number(document.getElementById("mHeight").value);
var mWeight=Number(document.getElementById("mWeight").value);

var calcM_1=mHeight / 100
var calcM_2=calcM_1 * calcM_1;
var calcM_3=Math.round(mWeight / calcM_2);

$("#outputM").text("Your BMI is: " + calcM_3);

 return false;
}
```

> Add "return false;" at the end.

Hope it helps